# TFS Maven Plugin for eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, tfs

Currently I'm using eclipse, subversion and maven. For this setup I installed Subversive, a svn kit, m2eclipse and a m2eclipse subversion connector. The screenshot shows the [m2eclipse svn connector](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Integration+with+Subversive).

[image]

I trying to find out if the same setup would work for Microsoft TFS as well.

There is a [Team Foundation Server Plugin for Eclipse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh301122.aspx) and there is a [maven plugin for tfs](http://maven.apache.org/scm/tfs.html) for release management. What I didn't find is a m2eclipse connector which allows checking out maven projects from tfs. Is there such a plugin, is it needed or are there alternatives?